# using httpclient in asmx webmethod

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous, asmx

is it possible to use httpclient to call a REST service inside an ASMX WebMethod?
The httpclient library is async and because asmx does not support async await (TAP), I used .Result to force the call to be sync. However, this time httpclient cannot make the call successfully and I get remote server actively refused connection error. if I run the same piece of code in a win forms application using async await or .Result, it works fine.

is this an issue with ASMX WebMethod?

```
[WebMethod]
public void Get(){

   //Sample (off the top of my head)
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   //more code
   Task.Run(()=> client.GetDocument()).Result;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var tt = Task.Run(() => client.GetAsync("http://immanuel.co")).Result;
-- the variable tt now contains the response and its fully sync

Comment: @Immanuel, you have done two things you should not do in Asp.Net - `.Result` and `Task.Run()`. [Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject a module in the pipeline to handle the processing instead of the actual .asmx code. But I would suggest before going to the trouble, just use `HttpWebRequest`.

Do not do `.Result`. Do not do `Task.Run()` in an Asp.Net context.

The module:

```
public class Proxy : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        var wrapper = new EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(DoAsyncWork);
        context.AddOnBeginRequestAsync(wrapper.BeginEventHandler, wrapper.EndEventHandler);
    }

    async Task DoAsyncWork(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // await... anything
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response. How can I use this class in the asmx webmethod?

Comment: You register the module in web.config or IIS. In the code you would have to check to see if the request was for your webservice, and if so, do your stuff. Otherwise jump out and let the asp pipeline continue. There are many resources for using modules, but unless you really need to go async for scalability I still suggest you use the synchronous `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: i understand. thank you very much for answering my question